# How to run prisma migrate deploy on amazon beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, database-migration, prisma

I am having difficulty running Prisma migrations on my Amazon Elastic Beanstalk environment. I have successfully deployed my application, but am unsure how to migrate the database. I have attempted to create a .ebextensions/00_migration.config file with the following command:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "npx prisma migrate deploy"
    leader_only: true
```

But I keep getting an error. Can someone please provide guidance on how to properly run Prisma migrations on an Amazon Elastic Beanstalk environment once deployed?

Comment: I was able to successfully run the Prisma migrations on my Amazon Elastic Beanstalk environment by connecting to it via SSH and configuring the security groups correctly. However, I am still curious about how to automate this process in the future.

Comment: Hello, I have successfully managed to run migrate deploy automatically after each build on Beanstalk. Did you include [this](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/deployment/deployment-guides/caveats-when-deploying-to-aws-platforms#aws-elastic-beanstalk) in the root of your project and add a `prisma generate` postinstall script to your package.json?